# Is the documentation of Merb as poor as it seems?

Tags: ruby, documentation, merb

I've read only good things about Merb, but the documentation on the [website](http://merbivore.com/) is basically the api reference, and right now there is no books already published.

Any resources about Merb?

I guess that I'll start to read the code, but it'd be nice to have another sources of information

Answer (score 2):

The wonderful [PeepCode](http://peepcode.com/) have got a [Merb PDF and screencast](http://peepcode.com/products/meet-merb-pdf-draft) available for $9.

Answer (score 2):

The source code is really readable, pretty compact and full of comments.

Then, each merb part have a complete README full of informations too.

You can read all this on github: http://github.com/wycats/merb/

Answer (score 1):

I think merb has been pretty bad about good example code, tutorials and updating dated information. I really like the project, but have been stung by this several times. Now that it has reached a semi stable 1.0 I really hope that some people step up and get a bunch of the docs up to date, add warnings to old docs and point it towards newer information. It should be great to see how they deal with supporting the project now that it is 1.0

Answer (score 1):

There's the [Merb Wiki](http://wiki.merbivore.com/) and also a community book project, you can see it at http://book.merbist.com/ and the source is on github: http://github.com/mattetti/merb-book/tree/master.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. As the website will tell you, Merb is a hacker's framework. Yehuda called it an experimentation ground in a recent infoq interview . There is a lack of good examples because the system has changed a lot since its inception. Dec pointed out the github pages. They are the best source of current documentation that I know of. With the release of 1.0 the API has become stable, which will hopefully lead to less broken code examples.
I can also highly recommend the #merb IRC channel on FreeNode. Friendly, smart people.